# C++ require a type specifer for all declarations

Tags: c++, class, static

I want to initialise an static attribut but I don't know why there is this error.

```
class LancerDisqueDur
{

private:
 static LancerDisqueDur *m_instance;

public:
 static LancerDisqueDur* instance();
 void afficherDetail();

};
```

And my .cpp

```
LancerDisqueDur::m_instance=NULL;

LancerDisqueDur* LancerDisqueDur::instance()
{
if(m_instance==NULL)
{
    m_instance=new LancerDisqueDur();
    std::cout << "Démarrage du disque" << std::endl;
}

return m_instance;
}
```

I think the instance is correctly initialized , no ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need the type of the static:

```
LancerDisqueDur* LancerDisqueDur::m_instance=NULL;
```

Note that you can greatly simplify the code by using a `static` instance inside the `static`instance()` method.

```
class LancerDisqueDur
{

public:
 static LancerDisqueDur& instance();
 void afficherDetail();
};

LancerDisqueDur& LancerDisqueDur::instance()
{
    static LancerDisqueDur instance;
    std::cout << "Démarrage du disque" << std::endl;
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Ho thanks. I never know it was necessary to set the type of an static attribut in an initialisation ..